# Carbon Credit for online transaction

Tags: android, flutter

How do I add carbon credits as a transaction system or how do integrate it the existing payment methods in  my Android application ?

I was looking into this but I didn't find it very helpful , [Carbon API](https://api.compensate.com/docs/#tag/Glossary)

I tried looking into existing projects on carbon credits and I was expecting to see how after certain transactions , the carbon credit is incremented and does the user become aware of that ?

I am interested on this from a developer point of view